# Readonly property of checkbox in Dojo is not working

Tags: forms, checkbox, dojo, submit, readonly

I am using Dojo 1.6. The question is regarding `dijit.form.CheckBox`.
I have a readonly checkbox on a form(*.jspx).
Am using Spring MVC 3.0,Roo 1.1.
when I click on that readonly checkbox, the value of that checkbox gets changed (From `true` to `false`) but an image of that checkbox doesn' t get changed.

Please refer following scenario and its observation-

I have a jspx with a checkbox with
   -  `readOnly` property is `TRUE`.
   -  `checked` property is `TRUE`.

When I click on that checkbox and submit the form I got following obeservations:
   -  an image of `readOnly` checkbox did not change at all.
   -  `checked` property is `FALSE`.

I tried following steps:
1. tried to remove `onClickEvent` of that checkbox but failed to remove
   2. added a `function` in which on every click event of checkbox, set `readOnly` property to `true` but this also did not work.

```
  function disableCheckbox(source) {
       var sourceWidget=dijit.byId("_"+source+"_id");
       sourceWidget.set("readOnly",true);
  }
```

I request you to throw some light on this problem.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're asking. Please update and pose a question. Something like "How can I disable the dijit.form.CheckBox?"

Comment: Please post your code and clarify the problem. We don't know anything about your checkbox (is it a regular html input or a dijit.form.CheckBox, etc...).